# Linear model what is $p(x|y_0)$

Tags: least-squares, conditional-probability, linear

If I have a linear model of the form:

$$x_i = \beta y_i + \alpha + \epsilon_i$$

where $\epsilon_i$ are samples from $\epsilon$, an independent and identically distributed random variable. I can find estimates $\hat{\beta}, \hat{\alpha}$ using ordinary least squares.

Given a value of $y=y_0$, can I write

$$p(x|y_0) = \hat{\beta} y_0 + \hat{\alpha} + p(\epsilon)$$

Comment: no, because produced value $x$ won't be a probability distribution. You can parametrize some probability distribution with this value. For example, you can assign mean of the gaussian equal to the $x$ and keep variance equal to some constant

Comment: You can do it with an expected value because it is a linear operator. However, the density function does not have this linear property. You have to see how $\beta y + \alpha$ changes the distribution of $\epsilon$. In the most common case, you have that $\epsilon$ is normally distributed and  $\beta y + \alpha$ shifts the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

No, you cannot write that. You can however consider $x|y_0$ as a translation of the random variable $\epsilon$. So

$$x|y_0 = \hat{\beta} y_0 + \hat{\alpha} + \epsilon$$

In expectation:

$$<x|y_0> = \hat{\beta} y_0 + \hat{\alpha} + <\epsilon>$$

And the higher moments will be the same as the moments of the noise distribution.

So $p(x|y_0)$ will have the same shape as $p(\epsilon)$, but shifted along the axis by $\hat{\beta} y_0 + \hat{\alpha}$.